# Python 3 Simple HTTPS server

Tags: python, https

I know you can create a simple HTTP web server in Python 3 using

```
python -m http.server
```

However is there a simple way to secure the connection to the WebServer, do i need to generate certificates? How would I do this?

Comment: Aside: it's much more common to have a "real" web server handle this, and only use Python to execute application code.