# Working example of Python's http.server with HTTPS?

Tags: python, openssl

I have a small open-source project: an extension of Python's http.server which allows for file uploading as well. I've received a feature request for HTTPS support, so now I am trying to test it with HTTPS, but none of the examples I've found for using HTTPS with http.server work.

So far, every example I've found suggest using ssl.wrap_socket() similar to in this one [Python 3 Simple HTTPS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705785/python-3-simple-https-server). The server seems to start fine but every request results in "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading".

I've tried generating the certificates using various commands:

```
# Attempt 1
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out server.key
openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in server.key -out server-2.key
openssl req -new -key server-2.key -out server.csr
openssl req -new -key server.key -x509 -days 365 -out server.crt

# Attempt 2
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes

# Attempt 3
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

In each case I left the fields of the certificate blank, except for the comm name / hostname which I set to "localhost". There weren't any obvious errors, other than the connection not working.

Edit: Figured it out. My test script was still sending the requests as HTTP instead of HTTPS.